# If statement based on listbox with PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So i have been having some issues with a if statement based on the PySimpleGui listbox element.
The code i have is:

```py
layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=['Listbox 1', 'Listbox 2', 'Listbox 3'], size=(30, 6))],
          [sg.Button('Next'), sg.Button('Quit')]]

window = sg.Window('PyK Mn', layout)

#############
# MAIN LOOP #
#############
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Quit':
        quit()
    elif event == 'Next':
        if values[0] == 'Listbox 3':
            print('3')
```

When i run this it returns 'Next' but no '3'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you print `values[0]`?

Comment: ['Listbox 3'] but i already tried ['Listbox 3'] and "['Listbox 3']" in the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `valuse[0]` just for selected list, like `['Listbox 3']` becasue `0` as key of listbox.

To check if `'Listbox 3'` selected, one more list index, like values[0][0],

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=['Listbox 1', 'Listbox 2', 'Listbox 3'], size=(30, 6))],
          [sg.Button('Next'), sg.Button('Quit')]]

window = sg.Window('PyK Mn', layout)

#############
# MAIN LOOP #
#############
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Quit':
        window.close()
        break
    elif event == 'Next':
        if values[0][0] == 'Listbox 3':
            print('3')
```